# html2canvas jspdf export not importing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, jspdf, html2canvas

when i download pdf of my resizable charts my export pdf file not looking well. when a page finish some chart length is more so it goes outside the page so i am seeding black line there how to fix thia? actually charts height and width is resizeable so i want when i export the whole charts the pdf should not looking broken. i am attatching screen shots and code. Thanks in advance.

```
const printDocument = () => {
    enqueueSnackbar('Downloading pdf...', {
      variant: 'success',
      autoHideDuration: 5000,
    });
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint1');
    html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
      const imgWidth = 210;
      const pageHeight = 295;
      const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;

      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4');
      let position = 0;

      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);

      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        pdf.addPage();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
      pdf.save('download.pdf');
    });
  };
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: no i cant add a break page or a3 because by doing this, this is something static. as i mention in my post charts are resizeble so it depends on each user they will give different height so issue will happen again. i want something like responsiveness? when chart height increase so pdf page height automatically should increase.

Comment: i give a3 so it increase the width of pdf and increase the height too and chart are repeating now and line break issue is still there

Comment: sorry i didn't get. can u make changes into code? i added the code in my post

Comment: i put code on codesandbox can u give a look? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/customizable-react-dashboard-with-chart-fork-forked-15rfpq?file=/src/Content.js

Comment: It's working i have checked it multiple times. i tried link in incognito window and on phone as well and its working like charm

Comment: i think something wrong with your browser. i found the solution for chrome browser.
https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document/

Comment: try codesandbox link in another browser or in incognito mode

Comment: hey did you check?

Comment: so what do you suggest for this kind of dynamic layout?

Comment: anyone could help me? no success till yet. this codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/customizable-react-dashboard-with-chart-fork-forked-15rfpq?file=/src/Content.js:1898-2587